# How to get the last row with data validation in excel?

Tags: excel

I have used the formula in the dropdown list of data validation list. As you can see if my data has blank cells they still appear in the dropdown. How can this be modified so that it does not list the blank cells in the dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

Add this code into your data validation source

```
=OFFSET(Data!$H$2,0,0,COUNTIF(Data!$H$2:$H$100,">"""))
```

Example:

```
=OFFSET(CustomersForm!$B$2,0,0,COUNTIF(CustomersForm!$B$2:$B$1000,">"""))
```

[image]

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$2,,,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$100),)
```

Adjust your `sheet` name and `cell` reference.